# How to migrate a database from a server to another

Tags: database, sql, phpmyadmin

I try the export method of phpmyadmin, but the user is exported with the data... so there is no way to re import it into another database without error message.

The old user is name : oldserver_username, and the new server user is called : some_text_server_name_new_user

So there is NO WAY i can have the same username to export-import... how can i export and re import without having to have username check or bypass that ?

i am completely lost in MySQL !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database user name/password is not stored in the database; it is only used to access the database. Change the username (and password, too) to the new values in wp-config.php.

And the problem might be access to the database via phpmyadmin; check your username/password in Cpanel or some other hosting control panel.

Comment: in phpmyadmin, the import fail... user (old one) not allow to access database

Comment: Your login/password is wrong; reset that in Cpanel or some other control panel at the host.